# C# Contract.Result type when comparing to null

Tags: c#, code-contracts

It is annoying than Contract.Result can not work out its type in some situations. See extract from manual below.

> **Method Return Values** Within postconditions the method's return value can be referred to via the expression `Contract.Result<T>()`, where T is replaced with the return type of the method. When the compiler is unable to infer the type it must be explicitly given. **For instance, the C# compiler is unable to infer types for methods that do not take any arguments.**

I have noticed that code snippet `cen` produces `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);` With String highlighted for edit.

Am I missing something, or can I just set the type to Object when comparing to null.
i.e. `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Object>() != null);`

Comment: Could you at least give your question a descriptive title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought that according to OO theory. That if we have nullable types. Then null conforms to all (nullable) types. Therefore it should work, so I wrote the tests below.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    class EnsureResult_nunit
    {
        [Test]
        public void testA()
        {
            var z = str1();
            var y = str2();
        }

        [Test, ExpectedException]
        public void testB()
        {
            var z = str3();
        }

        [Test, ExpectedException]
        public void testC()
        {
            var y = str4();
        }


        public string str1() 
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Object>() != null);
            return "";
        }

        public string str2()
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Object>() == null);
            return null;
        }

        public string str3()
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Object>() == null);
            return "";
        }

        public string str4()
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Object>() == null);
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

All tests passed.